# ParseError: not well-formed during reading file in python

Tags: python

I have this strange and bizarre error, if I run the program inside my computer all work well, but inside another computer the program stop immediately after reading the first byte in the file xml.

I use this part of code for read the file XML

```
    try:
                tree = ET.parse(filename)
                root = tree.getroot()
                
            except OSError as e:
                #traceback.print_exc(file=log)
                raise ValueError(filename)
                logger.exception(e) # Will send the errors to the file
                #handle_error("Could not read result file %s: %s", filename, e)
            
            except ET.ParseError as e:
                #traceback.print_exc(file=log)
                #e_type, e_val, e_tb = sys.exc_info()
                # traceback.print_exception(e, file=filename)
                raise ValueError(filename)
                logger.exception(e) # Will send the errors to the file
                #handle_error("Table file %s is invalid: %s", filename, e)

if root.attrib.get('versione') == 'FPR12' and root.tag == RefFattura:
```

the only difference inside the file XML are:
FIRST FILE:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="fatturapa_v1.2.xsl"?>
<p:FatturaElettronica xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:p="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" versione="FPR12" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2 http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/export/fatturazione/sdi/fatturapa/v1.2/Schema_del_file_xml_FatturaPA_versione_1.2.xsd">
<FatturaElettronicaHeader>
<DatiTrasmissione>
```

and the SECOND FILE XML are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns3:FatturaElettronica versione="FPR12" 
xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
xmlns:ns3="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2">
    <FatturaElettronicaHeader>
        <DatiTrasmissione>
```

the error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exportFattureElettroniche.py", line 675, in <module>
  File "xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1202, in parse
  File "xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 595, in parse
  File "<string>", line None
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exportFattureElettroniche.py", line 688, in <module>
ValueError: C:\Users\Mirko\OneDrive\Desktop\test\12_Dicembre\._IT00029780954_05E3L.xml
```

last point, the python file is then converted to exe with pyinstaller, this are the batch file:

```
pyinstaller  --log-level=WARN --additional-hooks-dir=. --hidden-import=pkg_resources.py2_warn --upx-dir=F:\mydir\upx-3.96-win64 --onefile exportFattureElettroniche.py
```

Comment: What does https://www.xmlviewer.org/ say? Do both xml files load?

Comment: yes both file are read, but in my computer all work well.. both if I try with the file py (inside visual code) and both if I try with exe compiled with pyinstaller

Answer (score 0):

You need to pay attention to the file you are trying to read. If the file is:
C:\Users\Mirko\OneDrive\Desktop\test\12_Dicembre._IT00029780954_05E3L.xml, it can't works. This seems, infact, the attribute file produced by a Mac writing into an smb export partition.

Comment: yes, the customers have one MAC and the XML file are generated by MAC, but after copy the file XML into another PC windows and use the python program...how can solve?